# Java parsing a string expression

Tags: java, regex

I have expression like below, and I need to parse them. 
Examples:

1. `Total volumes of A + Total volumes of B`
2. `Total sales of A / Total sales of B`
3. `Total Shipment  of A - Total Shipment of B`

When I get the string , I don't know which operation is present in the string. So using regex I want to parse each expression in java, and I should get this result.

`expression1 = Total volumes of A
expression2 = Total volumes of B
operator = +`

Can anyone help me with this. I want an efficient way to do this in java, there are 1000's of such  expression

Comment: You can use [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 1):

As @Pshemo stated, groups are the solution.

I did make the assumption that operator characters aren't part of the operands:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]+)\\s+([+\\-/*])\\s+([\\w\\s]+)");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Total volumes of A + Total volumes of B");

if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("operand 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("operator: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("operand 2: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Output:

```
operand 1: Total volumes of A
operator: +
operand 2: Total volumes of B
```

Comment: @Pshemo indeed, we only need to escape `-` since it would otherwise imply a range.